# Creating Skyrim mods for Xbox One?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, xbox-one

So Skyrim Xbox One came out recently. Consoles now have mod support. I really love the mods, and I'd like to crate some myself.
I've been looking for mod tools, and found two: SKSE and the creation kit. But as far as I know, these require a PC copy of the game.

Is there another modding tool that can be used for XB1?
Or is there a way to get the above two to work without a PC copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first: SKSE (SKyrim Script Extender) is not really a tool to create mods. It's a tool that allows mods you create to be more powerful, you still need to make the mods in the creation kit but your scripts will have more options.

SKSE is also not available for consoles, due to the fact that it can load and run DLLs.

Now to your question: The creation kit is used to create mods, it is only available for PC (when you see the interface you'll get why). You can't create mods on consoles, you can only upload them after they've been created on the PC.